# Including network and communication details in UML Sequence diagram

Tags: uml

I have a UML sequence diagram. Some consumer/Client sends a request, and the request flows through a P2P network and then through a Message bus. The message flow happens sequentially.

1.)P2P network consists of components A,B,C
2.)Message bus consists of D,E,F

My objective here is to differentiate between the sequences that happens in the P2P system as against the sequences that happen in the Message bus. In case of a visio, i can use different legends(Color coding) to differentiate between the two. While i do understand that UML sequence diagram is to depict, sequential and ordered flow of messages between components without bringing in deployment/infrastructure concerns. Those concerns are best handled by deployment diagrams. But is there a way to do it in UMl sequence diagram?One way would be to stereotype the components. is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Sequence diagrams are the right approach.  I suggest Activity Diagrams with two swim lanes will show things most clearly.  Your internal message bus and and your external P2P network falling into one swim lane each.  Make Activities that match your six components and stereotype those.  I use Activity and State Diagrams to model SOA systems using these [stereotypes](http://www.spamer.me.uk/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php/soa-profile.png) mapping services onto stereotyped Activities and Messages onto stereotyped states.

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes a lot of sense to me.